# How to change the voice of the person while he is calling to another person during the conversation by android code

Tags: android, call, voice-recognition, voice-recording

Is it possible to change the voice of the person while he is calling to another person during the conversation by android code ?

Are developers allowed to do such functionality in android application ?

Help me if you have any idea for the same!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK,

You might be able to play with the recorded voice, there are many apps on play store doing the same, even creating song from user's speech input so.. that's quite possible to convert the normal user's speech input with some different tone and tempo and those apps are really fun if they are well developed.

To use it with Call, I guess that won't be possible and Android should/will never provide such ability to developer to do so. "All for User Security Constraints"

---

You can keep the Question open by *not accepting this answer* and get more suggestions and links to demo from other users.

Comment: Its amusing to come across questions which sometimes highlight the expectations developers have from the Android platform, what it being open and so supposedly having means to circumvent basic security features :-)